# Workaround for okhttp 2.5 timeout change breaking socket.io-client

Tags: socket.io, okhttp

Between versions 2.4 and 2.5, okhttp apparently [changed its "lousy" socket timeout](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-250), causing [massive breakage](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java/issues/212) in the popular socket.io-client-java library.

Is there a workaround aside from sticking with okhttp 2.4?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your preferred timeouts with `OkHttpClient.setReadTimeout()`, etc.

Comment: (Use 0 for no timeout!)

Comment: This requires somehow obtaining the instance of `OkHttpClient` that socket.io-client uses internally.  I don't suppose there's a static method to change the *default* timeouts for `OkHttpClient`?

Comment: Nope, no static global configuration. If socket.io won't give you the OkHttp client to configure, that's particularly weak. How do you tweak TLS settings?!

Comment: There unavoidably *is* a global static configuration.  There's just no way to change it.